# Python regex to pick either regex A or regex B

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to create a regex statement that will choose one regex or the other, for example:

```
string = '123 Test String'   
pattern = r'( ?)([T](?P<name1>\w+))|([A](?P<name2>\w+))'
m = re.search(pattern, string)
```

Basically, I want the Regex to pick one regex of the other.

Comment: `re.search` will stop matching after the first match.

Comment: What's your actual question? Your second pattern should fail, because there isn't a word starts with `A`

Comment: Yeah, what is the question?  The regex you gave will search for either the first or the second pattern, what more are you asking?

Comment: `r'cat|dog?'` matches `cat`, `do` or `dog`.

Answer (score 0):

By using the alternation (or) operator "|" in your pattern you are effectively comparing your string against tow regular expressions. If your string matches the expression on either side of the "|", then re.search will return a MatchObject.

See the Python [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html):

Alternation, or the “or” operator. If A and B are regular expressions, A|B will match any string that matches either A or B. | has very low precedence in order to make it work reasonably when you’re alternating multi-character strings. Crow|Servo will match either Crow or Servo, not Cro, a 'w' or an 'S', and ervo.